# Неправильная работа pyzbar

Tags: python, telebot, qr

Суть кода: человек присылает qr в чате телеграма, он выгружается и расшифруется через pyzbar. Код работает прекрасно до того момента, пока не пришлется большой qr (имею в виду количество данных в нём). Маленькие коды с какой-то ссылкой расшифровываются спокойно, а вот с каким-то большим текстом pyzbar выдает ошибку:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Также заметил, что если код был изначально с форматом png, то большие\маленькие коды расшифровываются. А если же jpg, то выходит ошибка только с большими.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types="photo")
def get_qr(message):
# ВЫГРУЗКА ФАЙЛА ИЗ ТЕЛЕГИ
    inform = bot.get_file_url(message.photo[0].file_id)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    browser.get(inform)
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.quit()
# ТУТ ОЧИСТКА ИМЕНИ ОТ ЛИШНЕГО
    file = [f for f in os.listdir() if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*.jpg')]
    file1 = str(file)
    file2 = file1.replace("'","",2)
    file3 = file2.replace("[","")
    file4 = file3.replace("]","")
    file5 = file4

    d = decode(Image.open(file5))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, d[0].data.decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что выгружаемая фотография из телеграм всегда выходила в качестве 90х90. От этого и была проблема чтения `qr`, где много информации (он просто сжимался и ломался).

Вот измененная часть кода:

```
fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id   
file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
with open("image.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
    new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```